# Linux kernel compile error elf_x86_64 missing

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm using Ubuntu Linux 12.04 with the 3.11 kernel.

For my work I have to patch the kernel to make it realtime able.

So I downloaded the Linux 2.6.31.6 kernel with the patch and tried to patch, compile and instal it.

While I try to compile it there comes this error:

```
CC      arch/x86/vdso/vgetcpu.o
CC      arch/x86/vdso/vvar.o
VDSO    arch/x86/vdso/vdso.so.dbg

gcc: Error: elf_x86_64: File or directory not found
make[2]: *** [arch/x86/vdso/vdso.so.dbg] Error 1
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/vdso] Error 2
make: *** [arch/x86] Error 2
```

For the compilation of the RT 2.6... kernel I use the same configfile like the 3.11 (with some edited points of course) and I looked into the /arch/x86/vdso directory and the vdso.so.dbg file is missing (and I don't know where to get it).

I hope you can help me and if you need some further informations I will try to provide them.

Yours sincerely
Adrian

Comment: Why are you mixing 2.6 with 3.11? It's clearly asking for trouble.

Comment: I was told by my predecessor that it should run even though these are two different versions. But yeah, once I tried to patch the 3.11 kernel I was able to compile and install it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: There are many many many differences in these two kernels, even when it comes to files content and location. Probably that was the problem you have encountered.

Answer (score 5):

I changed in `arch/x86/vdso/Makefile`

```
VDSO_LDFLAGS_vdso.lds = -m elf_x86_64 [...]
...
VDSO_LDFLAGS_vdso32.lds = -m elf_x86 [...]
```

to

```
VDSO_LDFLAGS_vdso.lds = -m64 [...]
...
VDSO_LDFLAGS_vdso32.lds = -m32 [...]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how gcc is getting some flags from `arch/x86/vdso/Makefile`. Replacing the

```
VDSO_LDFLAGS_vdso.lds = -m elf_x86_64
```

with

```
VDSO_LDFLAGS_vdso.lds = -m64
```

should work.