# Error compiling Linux kernel 2.6 on a new version of GCC

Tags: linux, kernel, compilation, gcc

I downloaded Linux kernel 2.6.34 and I wanted to compile it with GCC v8.3.0 on Debian10. Initially, I had problems with PIE executables that I solved by adding `-fno-pie` to the Makefile's `CFLAGS`. I succeeded to run the build but it, eventually, failed with the following error:

```
gcc: error: elf_x86_64: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m’
make[2]: *** [/linux/arch/x86/vdso/Makefile:34: arch/x86/vdso/vdso.so.dbg] Error 1
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:366: arch/x86/vdso] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:884: arch/x86] Error 2
```

Taking a look at /linux/arch/x86/vdso/Makefile:34

```
28  VDSO_LDFLAGS_vdso.lds = -m elf_x86_64 -Wl,-soname=linux-vdso.so.1 \
29          -Wl,-z,max-page-size=4096 -Wl,-z,common-page-size=4096
30  
31  $(obj)/vdso.o: $(src)/vdso.S $(obj)/vdso.so
32  
33  $(obj)/vdso.so.dbg: $(src)/vdso.lds $(vobjs) FORCE
34          $(call if_changed,vdso)
```

It looks like the `-m elf_x86_64` option passed to the linker that caused this error.

After several other random hacks and frustrations, I thought maybe this 10yo kernel can never be compiled on a modern system and I decided to compile it on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS VM from 2012 which relatively has software versions (GCC v4.8) near the same kernel release year. Unfortunately, it didn't work and the same problem showed up again on GCC v4.8:

```
gcc: error: elf_x86_64: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m’
make[2]: *** [arch/x86/vdso/vdso.so.dbg] Error 1
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/vdso] Error 2
make: *** [arch/x86] Error 2
```

What is the reason behind this problem and how can I solve it ?

Comment: You are missing the definition of 32 vs  64 bit. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5802799/1216776. Option should be -m 32 or - m 64

Comment: See also that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662906/linux-kernel-compile-error-elf-x86-64-missing.